# Does Distributed TensorFlow support InfiniBand interconnections "out of the box"

Tags: tensorflow, distributed, grpc, infiniband

We have a cluster with InfiniBand interconnects.  I know that Distributed TF uses gRPC to handle network calls, but I was wondering if there was anything special required to gain the speed of InfiniBand connections when using the gRPC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the answer is no. 
And technically is not Tensorflow that would need the infiniband support but more the gRPC layer.

Doing a quick query for infiniband in the github gRPC repository and receiving zero results strengthens my assumption: https://github.com/grpc?query=infiniband